# Unable to get corresponding FHIR resource(Patient's data) in FHIR service

Tags: azure, azure-health-data-services

I've deployed [DICOM Cast](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md#deploy-via-azure-with-oss) successfully. And performed all the steps of [Sync Medical Imaging Server for DICOM metadata into FHIR Server for Azure](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/how-to-guides/sync-dicom-metadata-to-fhir.md). But unable to get the corresponding FHIR resources in FHIR service.

I've confusion in some steps of [this doc.](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/how-to-guides/sync-dicom-metadata-to-fhir.md)

1. While Setting the Authentication for your FHIR & DICOM App Services, I'm unable to set Audience, Authority, and Security: Enabled in DICOM service, and unable to set Security: Enabled in FHIR service.

[image]
2. While Updating the Key Vault for DICOM Cast, you mentioned "Search for your Service Principle" in a document. Under the select principal, Which principle should I select? User Principle or Enterprise Application Principle? If Enterprise Application Principle then which application should I choose?
[image]
Right now, I've not authenticated the DICOM service, and In the service principle, I've selected the user principle.

Here is the detailed container log:

```
 info: Azure.Identity[1]
      DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId: 
info: Azure.Identity[1]
      EnvironmentCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId: 
info: Azure.Identity[3]
      EnvironmentCredential.GetToken was unable to retrieve an access token. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId:  Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException (0x80131500): EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
info: Azure.Identity[1]
      WorkloadIdentityCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId: 
info: Azure.Identity[3]
      WorkloadIdentityCredential.GetToken was unable to retrieve an access token. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId:  Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException (0x80131500): WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
info: Azure.Identity[1]
      ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId: 
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] MSAL MSAL.NetCore with assembly version '4.54.1.0'. CorrelationId(0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4)
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] === AcquireTokenForClientParameters ===
      SendX5C: False
      ForceRefresh: False
      
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] 
      === Request Data ===
      Authority Provided? - True
      Scopes - https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com
      Extra Query Params Keys (space separated) - 
      ApiId - AcquireTokenForClient
      IsConfidentialClient - True
      SendX5C - False
      LoginHint ? False
      IsBrokerConfigured - False
      HomeAccountId - False
      CorrelationId - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4
      UserAssertion set: False
      LongRunningOboCacheKey set: False
      Region configured: 
      
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] === Token Acquisition (ClientCredentialRequest) started:
         Scopes: https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com
        Authority Host: login.microsoftonline.com
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:31Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] [Instance Discovery] Skipping Instance discovery because it is disabled. 
info: Azure.Core[1]
      Request [467f2d30-036f-41e2-ab12-9619b63ec6c7] GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=REDACTED
      Metadata:REDACTED
      x-ms-client-request-id:467f2d30-036f-41e2-ab12-9619b63ec6c7
      x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
      User-Agent:azsdk-net-Identity/1.10.0 (.NET 7.0.10; Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022)
      client assembly: Azure.Identity
info: Azure.Core[5]
      Response [467f2d30-036f-41e2-ab12-9619b63ec6c7] 200 OK (00.0s)
      Date:Thu, 14 Sep 2023 13:58:32 GMT
      Content-Type:application/json
      Content-Length:1438
      
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Checking client info returned from the server..
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Saving token response to cache..
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] ID Token not present in response. 
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Cannot determine home account id - or id token or no client info and no subject 
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving AT in cache and removing overlapping ATs...
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Looking for scopes for the authority in the cache which intersect with https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Intersecting scope entries count - 0
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] 
        === Token Acquisition finished successfully:
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4]  AT expiration time: 09/15/2023 12:56:16 +00:00, scopes: https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com. source: IdentityProvider
info: Azure.Identity[8]
      False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.10 Linux 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 [2023-09-14 13:58:32Z - 0c85f10d-5c3c-4f91-a149-c05e7048dae4] Fetched access token from host login.microsoftonline.com. 
info: Azure.Identity[2]
      ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2023-09-15T12:56:16.0260624+00:00
info: Azure.Identity[13]
      DefaultAzureCredential credential selected: Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential
info: Azure.Identity[2]
      DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://dicom.healthcareapis.azure.com ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2023-09-15T12:56:16.0260624+00:00
crit: Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core.Features.Worker.DicomCastWorker[0]
      Unhandled exception.
      Microsoft.Health.Dicom.Client.DicomWebException: Forbidden: Authorization failed.
         at Microsoft.Health.Dicom.Client.DicomWebClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, Func`5 additionalFailureInspector) in /_/src/Microsoft.Health.Dicom.Client/DicomWebClient.cs:line 219
         at Microsoft.Health.Dicom.Client.DicomWebClient.GetChangeFeedLatest(String queryString, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Health.Dicom.Client/DicomWebClient.ChangeFeed.cs:line 41
         at Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core.Features.DicomWeb.Service.ChangeFeedRetrieveService.RetrieveLatestSequenceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/converter/dicom-cast/src/Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core/Features/DicomWeb/Service/ChangeFeedRetrieveService.cs:line 41
         at Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core.Features.Worker.ChangeFeedProcessor.ProcessAsync(TimeSpan pollIntervalDuringCatchup, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/converter/dicom-cast/src/Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core/Features/Worker/ChangeFeedProcessor.cs:line 70
         at Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core.Features.Worker.DicomCastWorker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/converter/dicom-cast/src/Microsoft.Health.DicomCast.Core/Features/Worker/DicomCastWorker.cs:line 95
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

Here is the postman screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you include what **RBAC** roles you added to the managed identity?

Comment: I've provided the FHIR Data Contributor role to the FHIRClient App and user, and the DICOM Data Owner to the DICOM Client App and user.

Answer (score 0):

The error **403 Forbidden** usually occurs if you missed adding required roles like `FHIR Data Contributor` to the **ACI managed identity**.

When I tried to get Patient's data via Postman without adding roles, I too got **same error** with `403 Forbidden` status as below:

```
GET https://demofhir20.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to add  `FHIR Data Contributor` and `DICOM Data Owner` role to the [ACI managed identity](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md#deployment:%7E:text=Role%20assignments%20of%20DICOM%20Data%20Owner%20and%20FHIR%20Data%20Contributor%20to%20the%20ACI%20managed%20identity.) as you are generating access token using Managed Identity authentication:

[image]

After assigning the role, generate access token again and call `/patient` API where you will get **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://demofhir20.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[dicom-server/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md at main · microsoft/dicom-server (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md)

Comment: I've followed the steps you provided. But still unable to get corresponding FHIR resources.

Whenever I add a DICOM file to the DICOM server, The corresponding FHIR resource(patient's data) is not populated in the FHIR server.

I was able to get information of patients that I've added manually to my FHIR server.

Comment: Have you added `DICOM Data Owner` also to your ACI managed identity?

Comment: yes I have added.

Comment: So, you are getting information of patients that are manually added to FHIR server?

Comment: Yes, but unable to get information of the patient which is populated from the DICOM service to FHIR service.

Comment: Still, getting the same issue. Unable to get corresponding FHIR resources to My FHIR service.

After giving the FHIR Contributor and DICOM Data Owner Role to ACI Managed Identity, Are you able to get corresponding FHIR resources to FHIR service?

Comment: In Postman I'm able to get the results. Could you try generating bearer token via Postman and use it to call API?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating a bearer token via Postman and using it to call the API.

Comment: What flow you used to generate the token? Could you include that Postman screenshot by editing your question?

Comment: Are you referring this doc: https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md for deploying dicomcast?

And for Sync Dicom metadata to FHIR are you using this doc? : https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/how-to-guides/sync-dicom-metadata-to-fhir.md

Comment: I've attached postman screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to follow the below steps of Authentication for your FHIR & DICOM App services.

Then you will be able to get corresponding FHIR resource(Patient's data) in FHIR service.
[image]

Comment: Please, post the authentication steps as text and not as picture.